# Unhandled rejection error with Bluebird, Jasmine and an async function

Tags: node.js, jasmine, bluebird, babeljs

Consider the following (contrived) example:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';

const resolvedPromise = () => {
    return Promise.resolve('Test');
};

const asyncFunc = async (asyncResource) => {
    await resolvedPromise();
    await asyncResource.fetchItem();
};


describe('async/await', () => {
    it('should throw an error', (done) => {
        const mockAsyncResource = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockAsyncResource', ['fetchItem']);

        const mockError = Promise.reject(new Error('HTTP 401 - Access Denied'));

        mockAsyncResource.fetchItem.and.returnValue(mockError);

        return asyncFunc(mockAsyncResource).catch(err => {
            expect(err.message).toEqual('HTTP 401 - Access Denied');
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

I receive the following output:

```
1) async/await
Unhandled rejection Error: HTTP 401 - Access Denied 
... (error stack trace)

✔ should throw an error
```

The spec passes, but Bluebird complains about the unhandled rejection error.

Because of the blocking nature of awaits, does the `mockError` report it's unhandled rejection before the second `await` has a chance to call (and handle) the `mockError` promise?

What is the best way to handle this scenario? I've discovered [`promise.suppressUnhandledRejections()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/suppressunhandledrejections.html), is it as simple as using this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a problem caused by mixing 2 different types of promises. You are creating your resolved/rejected mock promises using bluebird's `Promise` but the await returns the native `Promise`.

If you try the following on the chrome console, you will see it works as you expected when only using native promises:

```
let resolvedPromise = () => {
    return Promise.resolve('Test');
};

let asyncFunc = async (asyncResource) => {
    await resolvedPromise();
    await asyncResource.fetchItem();
};

let mockAsyncResource = {fetchItem: () => Promise.reject(new Error("foo"))};

asyncFunc(mockAsyncResource).catch((e) => console.log('handled'))
```

If you want to stick with creating bluebird promises, you might need to wrap your async function with bluebird's [`Promise.try`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.try.html), although I haven't been able to test this:

```
let asyncFunc = async (asyncResource) => {
    return Promise.try(async () => {
        await resolvedPromise();
        await asyncResource.fetchItem();
    });
};
```

Comment: Ah, good catch! I was using Bluebird elsewhere in my code and got comfortable with importing it. Haven't considered the type of promise `await` returns.

Comment: Sure enough switching to the native Promise in the spec resolved the issue, so I'm happy to mark this as the answer.

Also... interestingly enough, I went ahead and tested it further, Bluebird emits an unhandled rejection error before the native Promise is even returned. Not sure if this implies that it could be a timing issue, or just incompatibilities between the Promise types like you suggested.

Comment: I guess you could always test the idea of the timing issue by playing with timeouts but I suspect more about incompatibilities and bluebird's promise being continued by the promise returned in the await. However I can't really tell for sure!